# Hide progress dialog only for a finite/fixed time

Tags: android, timeout, progressdialog

I have a progress dialog which is shown during some running action.

If the action hasn't executed for a given time, I want to dismiss the dialog and the action. How do I implement this?

I currently have these two methods, which stop and start my async action and dialog:

```
private void startAction()
{
    if (!actionStarted) {
        showDialog(DIALOG_ACTION);
        runMyAsyncTask();
        actionStarted = true;
    }
}

private void stopAction()
{
    if (actionStarted) {
        stopMyAsyncTask();
        actionStarted = false;
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_ACTION);
    }
}
```

i.e. I want to do something like this when the time is out:

```
onTimesOut()
{
    stopAction();
    doSomeOtherThing();
}
```

Comment: Use TimerTask it will make your life easy.
Run a task after fixed time which will cancel the async task if not started within given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a simple timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        stopAction();
    }
};

timer.schedule(task, 1000);
```

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to add, that my async action can be stopped before time is out. Then I need to cancel my timer too. Is it then enough to simple cancel it in stopAction() method?

Comment: in the postExecute of your asyncTask, you can call timer.cancel();

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a `Thread` or a `TimerTask`. Pause it X seconds, then if your task is not yet finished, force finish it and dismiss dialog.

So one implementation could be :

```
private void startAction() {
    if (!actionStarted) {
        actionStarted = true;
        showDialog(DIALOG_ACTION); //This android method is deprecated
        //You should implement your own method for creating your dialog
        //Run some async worker here...
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                if (!actionFinished) {
                    stopAction();
                    //Do other stuff you need...
                }
            }
        });
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, 5000); //will be executed 5 seconds later
    }
}

private void stopAction() {
    if (!actionFinished) {
        //Stop your async worker
        //dismiss dialog
        actionFinished = true;
    }
}
```